# How to check for multiple equal statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

At the moment I'm using jQuery to do a `click` function where it checks to see if the clicked element has an attribute equal to three different values.

Is there a neater way of writing it?

```
$('body').on('click','svg a', function(e){
    if ($(this).attr('xlink:href') =='#congo' || $(this).attr('xlink:href') =='#onshore' || $(this).attr('xlink:href') =='#sea'){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Start with the most obvious, and use a variable to hold the attribute instead of creating 3 jQuery objects to fetch it 3 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe $.inArray solution?

```
$.inArray($(this).attr('xlink:href'), ['#congo', '#onshore', '#sea']) != -1
```

Comment: Should be != -1 The array is 0 indexed :)

Comment: Thanks, every time the same mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

```
['#congo','#onshore','#sea'].indexOf($(this).attr('xlink:href')) > -1
```

Comment: browser support isn't best for array `indexOf` but i'm sure you already know this.

Answer (score 0):

with regex (pure JS)

```
$(document.body).on('click','svg a', function(e){
    var a = $(this).attr('xlink:href'),
        match = a.match(/#congo|#onshore|#sea/);
    if( match && match[0] == a )
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

Try

v2

```
if (/^(#congo|#onshore|#sea)$/.test($(this).attr("xlink:href"))) {    
    e.preventDefault();
   }
```

Example

```js
$('body').on('click','svg a', function(e){
    
    if (/^(#congo|#onshore|#sea)$/.test($(this).attr("xlink:href"))) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#other").hide();
    console.log($(this).attr("xlink:href"));
    } else {
      $("#other").show()
    } 
});
```

```css
#other {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="140" height="30"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <a xlink:href="#congo"
     target="_blank">
    <rect height="30" width="120" y="0" x="0" rx="15"/>
    <text fill="white" text-anchor="middle" 
          y="21" x="60">#congo</text>
  </a>
</svg>
<svg width="140" height="30"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <a xlink:href="#onshore"
     target="_blank">
    <rect height="30" width="120" y="0" x="0" rx="15"/>
    <text fill="white" text-anchor="middle" 
          y="21" x="60">#onshore</text>
  </a>
</svg>
<svg width="140" height="30"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <a xlink:href="#sea"
     target="_blank">
    <rect height="30" width="120" y="0" x="0" rx="15"/>
    <text fill="white" text-anchor="middle" 
          y="21" x="60">#sea</text>
  </a>
</svg>
<svg width="140" height="30"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <a xlink:href="#other">
    <rect height="30" width="120" y="0" x="0" rx="15"/>
    <text fill="white" text-anchor="middle" 
          y="21" x="60">#other</text>
  </a>
</svg>
<div id="other">other</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/qeux09gr/

Comment: still won't work. it doesn't do what you think it does. for example -> `/2|3/.test('333')` gives `true`.

Comment: @vsync Tried Snippet ? See `console` at this page , jsfiddle. `$(this).attr("xlink:href")` is only a _single_ element - not a collection. Is either one of `/#congo|#onshore|#sea/` , or not. The example provided at above comment actually returns desired results for the requirement of present Question. i.e.g., if `$(this).attr("xlink:href")` is not one within regex , `e.preventDefault()` will not be called . Try clicking `#other` at `Stack Snippet` , or jsfiddle . Thanks

Comment: it works because you have little error margin so you never get it to fail, but for example it will fail for the value `#congo2`. it will think it's `#congo`. therefore, you are not protecting your code from such things, as I was saying in my earlier comment.